# Elements of infinite order in the topological mapping class group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, mapping-class-groups, surgery-theory

Let $M$ be a closed topological manifold, and let $\operatorname{MCG}(M):=\operatorname{Homeo}(M)/\operatorname{Homeo}_0(M)$ denote the topological mapping class group of $M$ ($\operatorname{Homeo}_0(M)$ denotes the identity component of $\operatorname{Homeo}(M)$).  More generally, we could let $M$ be compact with boundary and consider homeomorphisms fixing the boundary.

> What known methods/invariants can be used to certify that a given element $\varphi\in\operatorname{MCG}(M)$ has infinite order?

Of course, $\varphi$ might have infinite order for homotopical reasons, but I am primarily interested in finer invariants.  So, for the sake of this question, let's assume $\varphi$ is homotopic to the identity as maps $M\to M$.  Of course, if $M$ has boundary, then this means homotopic through maps fixing the boundary.

For instance, the kernels in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/35909) are not detected by their action on homotopy, however unfortunately they are purely torsion (though I would still like to know how they are detected).

The focus of this question is on the high-dimensional case, though an answer in any dimension $\geq 4$ would be interesting.

Comment: If $M$ has boundary, then a homeomorphism will induce a mapping class on the boundary, and that can lead to interesting obstructions.  (Consider a three-dimensional handlebody and a Dehn twist about a disk).  If $M$ is non-compact, then a homeomorphism will induce a permutation of the ends of $M$.  (Consider a thickened tree.)  So - do you have side conditions on $M$ to eliminate these kinds of "dimension-reducing" techniques?

Comment: @Sam Nead: The easiest way to state the question so its answer is interesting is just to restrict to closed manifolds (edited accordingly).

Comment: If $G(M)$ is the monoid of homotopy self-equivalences of $M$, and $H(M)=Homeo(M)$,  then your question is about the kernel of $\pi_1 BH(M)\to\pi_1 G(M)$ which by the homotopy exact sequence of the fibration comes from $\pi_1 G(M)/H(M)$. As in Hatcher's survey in the linked answer one understands $G(M)/H(M)$ is two stages via the intermediate space $\tilde{H}(M)$ of blocked  homeomorphisms. Rationally one can estimate $G(M)/\tilde H(M)$ by the surgery exact sequence. The other stage $\tilde H(M)/H(M)$ is sort of controlled by the concordance space of $M$ via Hatcher's spectral sequence.

Comment: (cont.) A slower explanation of the above (for the analogous case of diffeomorphisms) can be found in section 8 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.03475.

Comment: typo in my comment: $\pi_1 G(M)$ should have been $\pi_1 BG(M)$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's an example of $f$ homotopic to the identity, but of infinite order in $\mathrm{MCG}(M)$ (if possible of minimal dimension)?

Comment: @YCor: I did not initially see that you are asking for an infinite order one, hence I deleted the hasty comment; I did not check the order.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Anyway it provides examples in dimension 3 of homeomorphisms isotopic and not homotopic to the identity (I restore the interesting link: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938386900030); the torsion  examples in the link given by John in the post being in dimension $\ge 5$. I have some rough remembrance that in dimension $\le 2$, isotopic=homotopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me suppose that $M$ is a closed manifold of dimension $d$, and let $\varphi : M \to M$ be a diffeomorphism / homeomorphism which is homotopic to the identity, and choose such a homotopy $h_t$. The mapping torus $X_\varphi$ of $\varphi$ is a smooth / topological manifold fibering over $S^1$, and our choice of homotopy $h_t$ yields a preferred homotopy equivalence
$$ H : X_\varphi \longrightarrow S^1 \times M.$$

For each cohomology class $v \in H^{d-4i+1}(M;\mathbb{Q})$ we may form
$$\int_{X_\varphi} p_i(TX_\varphi - H^*TM) \smile H^*(1 \otimes v) \in \mathbb{Q}$$
where $p_i$ is the (rational) Pontrjagin class. This defines a linear functional $H^{d-4i+1}(M;\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathbb{Q}$ which is Poincare dual to a class $\xi_i \in H^{4i-1}(M;\mathbb{Q})$.

Morally this class measures the following: on the one hand $\varphi$, by virtue of being a homeomorphism, preserves the rational Pontrjagin class $p_i(M)$, so preserves a given cocycle representative $c$ up to a "preferred" coboundary. On the other hand, the homotopy $h_t$ gives another coboundary for $c-\varphi^*c$; the difference between these cobounding cochains is thus a cycle, and it represents the cohomology class $\xi_i$.

In principle $\xi_i$ is an invariant of the pair $(\varphi, h_t)$. However, a different choice of homotopy $h_t'$ yields a homotopy equivalence $H'$ which differs from $H$ by postcomposition by a homotopy automorphism of $S^1 \times M$ which i) is over $S^1$ and, ii) fixes a fibre $M \times \{*\}$. This means that for each $v$ we have
$$(H')^*(1 \otimes v) = H^*(1 \otimes v) + H^*(u \otimes \bar{v})$$
for some $\bar{v}$, where $u \in H^1(S^1;\mathbb{Q})$ is the canonical class. But
$$\int_{X_\varphi} p_i(TX_\varphi - H^*TM) \smile H^*(u \otimes \bar{v})$$
can be written as
$$\int_{S^1 \times M} (H^{-1})^*(p_i(TX_\varphi-H^*TM)) \smile (u \otimes \bar{v}) = \int_M p_i(TM-TM) \cup \bar{v}=0$$
so in fact $\xi_i$ only depends on $\varphi$.

As $X_{\varphi \circ \psi}$ is cobordant to $X_{\varphi} \sqcup X_{\psi}$, one sees that $\xi_i(\varphi \circ \psi) = \xi_i(\varphi) + \xi_i(\psi)$. In particular if $\xi_i(\varphi) \neq 0$ for some $i$ then $\varphi$ has infinite order.

There is a theorem due to Sullivan that a simply-connected high-dimensional manifold is determined "up to finite ambiguity" by its homotopy type and rational Pontrjagin classes. The analogous statement for automorphisms of simply-connected (or perhaps 2-connected?) manifolds says that elements in
$$\mathrm{Ker}(\pi_0(Top(M)) \to \pi_0(G(M)))$$
(or the smooth analogue) are determined up to finite ambiguity by their associated $\xi_i$'s. This can (surely?) be proved using the surgery exact sequence.

Comment: It seems your argument is similar to pp.322-323 of Sullivan's "Infinitesimal computations in topology" where he discusses the kernel of the map that sends isotopy classes of diffeomorphisms to their homotopy classes. The link is http://archive.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1977__47__269_0.pdf.